# Dirichlet convolution of multiplicative functions

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Are there two nonzero arithmetic functions,say $f,g$, which are not multiplicative but their Dirichlet convolution is multiplicative?

Comment: Do you mean that $f(n)$ is a nonzero integer for all positive integer $n$ and similarly for $g(n)$?

Answer (score 2):

Take an invertible non-multiplicative function $f$ and some multiplicative function $h$. Then $g = f^{-1} \ast h$ is not multiplicative (otherwise $f^{-1} = (f^{-1} \ast h) \ast h^{-1} = g \ast h^{-1}$ would be multiplicative) but $f \ast g = h$ is.

Comment: But for $f^{-1}$ we need to have $f(1)\neq 0$. So something like the partition function works

Comment: $n^2+n$ would be even easier to think of

Comment: Ah thanks, added the invertible assumption.

Comment: No. If $f(1)\neq 0$ then let $g$ be s.t $f*g=I$. Then $g(1)=1/f(1)$. Now for $n>1$ we have $f(1)g(n)+\sum_{d|n,d<n}f(n/d)g(d)=0$ and supposing we found out $g(d)$ for $d<n$ we can define $g(n)$ from the above equation.

Comment: Ok, so we cannot take then $f(n)=\Lambda(n)$, the von Mangoldt function, which is not multiplicative, but also not invertible, because $\Lambda(1)=0$. I wantedt to try $\Lambda \ast \Lambda$.

Comment: $f(n)=0,f(1) = 1, f(6) = -6$ then $F(s) = 1-6^{-s}, F^{-1}(s) =\frac{1}{1-6^{-s}}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (6^k)^{-s}, f^{-1}(n) = 0, f^{-1}(6^k) = 1$ and $f \ast f^{-1}(n) = 0,f \ast f^{-1}(1)=1$ is completely multiplicative while $f,f^{-1}$ are not multiplicative @ArpanDas